# C++ I know the array length but was wondering if a cleaner way of defining the array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I have the following:

```
Action* actions[];
```

within an ActionBar class.

I would like in its constructor to do something like this:

```
actions = {
    new Action( new Image( gfx, "Images/ActionBar/Push001.png", 200, 200, TRUE ), 0, 200, 200, 200, 200 ),      
    new Action( new Image( gfx, "Images/ActionBar/Pull001.png", 200, 200, TRUE ), 1, 200, 200, 200, 200 )
};
```

Originally I was doing:

```
Action* actions[ 2 ];
```

Then in constructor:

```
actions[ 0 ] = new Action( new Image( gfx, "Images.....    
actions[ 1 ] = new Action( new Image( gfx, "Images.....
```

What's the best way of doing this? so that in the end I can in my game loop do something like

```
SomeFunctionIPassAnActionInto( actionBar->actions[ 0 ] );
```

**Edit:: changed the question slightly**, I always know there will be 5 actions, so if I did

```
Actions* actions [ 5 ];
```

How would I declare the array elements like this:

```
actions = {
   new Action( "push" ),
   new Action( "pull" ),       
   new Action( "bla" ),
   new Action( "ble" ),       
   new Action( "blo" )
}
```

kind of thing

Comment: Don't you want std::vector?

Comment: I've edited total of question, i'm not so fussed about dynamic length, I will know it's always 5 so I was wondering if I can do the first technique to declare the entires rather than having to say 0 = bla, 1 = bla

Comment: C++11 brace initializers would do the trick

Comment: It's still not clear what the question is: do you want to declare an array without hardcoding the number of elements? Are you looking for a way to transform an array of strings to your target type without repeating all of the boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you can initialize arrays in the *ctor-initializer*.

```
ActionBar::ActionBar()
    : actions {
        new Action( new Image( gfx, "Images/ActionBar/Push001.png", 200, 200, TRUE ), 0, 200, 200, 200, 200 ),      
        new Action( new Image( gfx, "Images/ActionBar/Pull001.png", 200, 200, TRUE ), 1, 200, 200, 200, 200 )
      }

{
}
```

Comment: Having some trouble getting it to work. it says it needs parenthesis (). VS 2012 is c++ 11 right? Do I need to add a header?

Comment: @JamesT: VS2012 has only a few parts of C++11.  Install Update 2 which was just released for better C++11 support, but this feature may still not be available.

Answer (score 0):

```
How would I declare the array elements like this:

actions = {
   new Action( "push" ),
   new Action( "pull" ),       
   new Action( "bla" ),
   new Action( "ble" ),       
   new Action( "blo" )
}
```

The simplest way to get this to work would be to define a constructor for `Action` that takes one of `char const*`, `char const* const*` or `std::string const&` that then forwards this argument (possibly with some sort of translation from the examples you've show) to the Image constructor (since image is a member, you'd need to do something in the initializer list like `_image(new Image(translate(arg)))` where `translate` is a function you defined that turns `push` into `Images/ActionBar/Push001.png`).